# Summing time hh:mm:ss keeps going to zero

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with a time in hh:mm:ss.

In VBA code it equals zero.
When I create a formula in the cell sum(E27:E33) it also goes to zero.

```vb
Sub sumTime()
Dim lrow2 As Long
Dim t As Double

lrow2 = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

t = 0
For i = lrow To 27 Step by - 1
    t = t + Worksheets("Summary").Cells(i, 5).Value
Next
Worksheets("Summary").Cells(lrow2 + 2, 5).Value = t
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Your times are stored as text and not a number.

Comment: @ScottCraner thannnks for the suggestion, but I have converted it to a number and  nothing has changed. Very strange

Comment: If the values are still left aligned then they're still text - the most reliable way to convert them to numbers is to enter `1` in a "numeric" blank cell, copy that cell, select your time-value cells, then _Paste Special_ -> _Multiply_

Comment: @jovi679 How did you convert them?  Changing the format of the cells does **not** convert them.  Doing an arithmetic operation or using a function is usually required.

Answer (score 0):

You problem with a date format data in the Excel is an old headake. Try this:

```
 For i = lrow To 27 Step by - 1     
     t = CDate(t + Worksheets("Summary").Cells(i, 5).Value)  
 Next
```

if this won't work then try this

```
 For i = lrow To 27 Step by - 1
     Worksheets("Summary").Cells(i, 5).Value=CDate(Worksheets("Summary").Cells(i, 5).Value)
     t = t + Worksheets("Summary").Cells(i, 5).Value) 
 Next
```